Why does this Vedic Hymn call Vayu the son-in-law of Tvashtar?
While reading the Rigveda I came across the following hymn:

त्वष्टु॒र्जामा॑तरं व॒यमीशा॑नं रा॒य ई॑महे । सु॒ताव॑न्तो वा॒युं द्यु॒म्ना जना॑सः ॥
त्वष्टुर्जामातरं वयमीशानं राय ईमहे । सुतावन्तो वायुं द्युम्ना जनासः ॥
tvaṣṭur jāmātaraṃ vayam īśānaṃ rāya īmahe | sutāvanto vāyuṃ dyumnā janāsaḥ ||

Translation:

We, the offerers of Soma, solicit riches from the sovereign, the son- in-law of Tvaṣṭā; (may we become) wealthy.

The details of the mantra show that it is dedicated to Vayu:

Ṛṣi (sage/seer): viśvamanā vaiyaśvo vyaśvo vāṅgirasaḥ;
Devatā (deity/subject-matter): vāyu:;
Chandas (meter): nicṛduṣṇik ;
Svara (tone/note): Swar;

Let me add that Tvashtar is another name of Vishwakarma whose daughter was married to Surya and the story is mentioned in another verse of Rigveda:

Tvashtar prepares the bridal of his Daughter: all the world hears the tidings and assembles. But Yama's Mother, Spouse of great Vivasvān, vanished as she was carried to her dwelling.

So my question is why Vayu is being referred to as the son-in-law of Tvashtar when it was Surya who married his daughter?

I think some scholars consider Tvasta to be different from Vishwakarma.

Yes that's a possibility that I had also explored in an answer but not applicable here since  the verse in the question as well as the one about his daughter's marriage with Surya mention Tvashtar not Vishwakarma check this hymn: https://sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10017.htm
